# Can you install and boot off a new OS as root?

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I have root on my computer but I can't edit the BIOS and so I can't boot from a USB/CD etc.  I could plug in a new hard drive but I would like to know if I can install and boot off a new install of Ubuntu without doing that.

> Is it possible to install a new version of Ubuntu and edit grub to
>   make it point to it somehow without have to boot off an external device?

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu

Comment: @imbuedHope Sadly not. In fact I tried that first to upgrade from 14 to 16 and it completely destroyed my install which is why I would like to install a fresh version of ubuntu now.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean you cant edit the BIOS? 
 - Are you not sure how, or do you have SecureBoot enabled??

The only way I can think of that you wouldnt be able to get into the BIOS would be if there was an admin password set on the machine which could be wiped by resetting CMOS.

Comment: There is an admin password indeed. I suppose I could open it up and reset the CMOS  but I would be interested to know if this can be avoided.

Comment: All you have to do to reset the CMOS is jump the correct pins, I would definitely research it first if you're not sure how to do it on that particular machine. The quickest and easiest way is to reseat the CMOS battery.

Comment: Thanks. In the worst case I will open it up and see if I can look up the motherboard to see how to do that.

Comment: You can usually find the correct documentation in the manufacturer guides on their support sites. Looking up the MoBo info will probably take you down a rabbit hole you dont want to go down, when checking the manufacturer directly would yield the best and quickest results. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks but the motherboard was bought separately so I will have to look that up.